# Boy playing ball has to run inside to avoid a hail of diamonds

Tags: story-identification, short-stories

I read this in a collection of sci-fi short stories when I was in elementary school, so circa mid-to-late 1980s.  It might have been published by Scholastic.
It's a very short story.

It may have been set on Mars; the planet is low gravity.  Sometime in the future, this planet, it could be the Moon or Mars, has been colonized.

A boy who's been out by himself playing baseball; his ball and bat are futuristic and the ball comes back to him. Then the boy is running home because of a "hail" warning, and his mother is possibly shouting at him from the door to run faster because the "hail" could kill him.

Later on, after the storm is over, trucks are coming to collect the "hail" on the ground.  The mother wonders to herself why the people on Earth found these clear shiny rocks so enticing.  (I think it's made clearer that they're diamonds, but I'm not sure.)

Comment: Huh. Apparently, that's a theory about Saturn and Neptune, that it rains diamonds there. Haven't found anything yet, though.

Comment: Probably not Steve Buick's "Diamond Rain" (https://web.archive.org/web/20160110125552/http://www.storiesofstevebuick.com/#Diamond-Rain)

Comment: @FuzzyBoots - I thought of that one and discounted it

Comment: I read this in the early eighties! I, too, Googled for the title but can't find it. I remember the boy being struck by a diamond and having it removed. (I think)

Comment: I also read this in Elementary. It's likely, then, that it was in a Language Arts textbook.

Comment: real hail on Earth can get pretty large and indeed can/has killed people and animals. i do not know if this happens in the usa. the idea is, the stones grow by accretion and they somehow get bounced around in the clouds by wind before getting so  heavy they fall. if they reach golf ball size, watch out!

Comment: ’ve been on the hunt for this same book for ages now. It also contained a short story where a spaceship gets caught in a net in space. The pilot gets out to cut himself free and notices a nearby planet is getting closer and closer. It turns out to be a giant spider who eats him. This was also depicted on the cover.

Comment: I recall this as well, also late 80s/early 90s. I think it was in a book in my elementary school library that was a collection of short stories. I remember a single crsytal or diamond struck the boy and embedded in his thigh like a sliver.

Answer (score -2):

There was a kids book in the 70's called Zillions that was abit like that , published by Penguin books i think

Comment: Hi, welcome to the site. You could improve this answer by [edit]ing it to explain why you think this might be the correct story, i.e. the ways in which it matches the one described in the question. Also note that the querent indicated that they were looking for a short story, not a book.

Comment: There don't appear to be any stories with the [title "Zillions"](http://www.isfdb.org/cgi-bin/adv_search_results.cgi?USE_1=title_title&O_1=contains&TERM_1=zillion&C=AND&ORDERBY=title_title&ACTION=query&START=0&TYPE=Title).

Comment: @DavidW - I believe OP is referring to Trillions by David Fisk (https://scifi.stackexchange.com/a/260740/20774) which doesn't match the description of the story, aside from a child being present as diamond-like objects fall from the sky.

Comment: That is what i meant, sorry i read it along time ago. Thankyou for working out what i didn't know i knew.  :)

Comment: @valorum It's actually Nicholas Fisk, although you may be conflating his pen name with his real name (David Higginbottom). Great author who was kind enough to reply to a letter from me many years ago!

Comment: @Peter - It is indeed Nicholas Fisk