# Does anyone remember the name of an old short story set on a planet with diamond rains?

Tags: story-identification

I think I read it in some sort of story compilation book, like one of those 'Best science fiction of 1981'-type things. It might have been as old as the 1960s though.

The main character was a young boy who was playing outside when an air-raid siren sounded, and he had to run for the house or be killed by the diamonds falling from the sky.

Comment: I don't recognise the story. I think that "air-raid siren" suggests not too long after World War II, so perhaps closer to the 60s than the 80s.

Comment: I wonder if it's the same story [this old question](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/34812/help-with-story-book-title-please-possible-scholastic-circa-mid-late-1980s) was asking about?

Comment: Is this prompted by the recent simulations of diamond rain formation in conditions similar to those on gas giants?

Comment: http://bestsciencefictionstories.com/2012/02/09/diamond-rain-by-steve-buick/?

Comment: Adamant - yes, that's what made me remember it. I think I read it maybe 20 years ago.

Comment: User14111 - yes!!! That is exactly right.

Comment: @Valorum - Thanks for the link - I was able to read Diamond Rain using the Internet Archive [https://web.archive.org/web/20141021153457/storiesofstevebuick.com/#Diamond-Rain](here), but it's not the same story.