# Young adult scifi short story collection with spider planet and crystal rain

Tags: story-identification, spaceship, space

I’m looking for a collection of young adult science fiction short stories. I read it in the 90s. The cover had a very vintage pulp look to it. It depicted a starship caught in a web, with a planet in the background with glowing eyes and spider legs coming out of it. I think there was also a purple planet in the background. I seem to recall the title being super generic, like “Tales in Space” or something.

I can only remember two of the stories within it. One was depicted on the cover. A starship gets tangled in a thick, steel-like net in space. The pilot jets out and attempts to cut the ship free using some kind of laser torch, only to slowly realize that the nearby planet keeps getting closer and closer. It ends with the pilot realizing it’s a giant spider creature and it is about to devour him.

The other story I remember less about. It features two boys out playing on a planet when it starts to rain crystal shards. Parents are screaming for the kids to get inside, because the rain is deadly. One kid takes a crystal to the shoulder and it slices right into him.

That’s about all I got. I’ve seen a couple posts on random forums of people describing the crystal rain story, but never seen it identified.

Comment: We have at least one question here about the crystal rain story, but no successful identifications.  Maybe if we can tie them together we can finally identify it!

Comment: Probably the same target as this https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/168074/does-anyone-remember-the-name-of-an-old-short-story-set-on-a-planet-with-diamond - a commentator also remarked on the "spaceship caught in a spider's web" story in the same anthology