# Old SF short about precious gems that fall as rain

Tags: story-identification, short-stories

A friend asks:

> There's some Golden Age sci-fi story where some planet has gems that
> fall in the rain and they're worthless there but scooped up and sold
> to idiot off-worlders.

Does this ring a bell for anyone?

Comment: Possibly the same question as https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/168074/does-anyone-remember-the-name-of-an-old-short-story-set-on-a-planet-with-diamond or https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/34812/boy-playing-ball-has-to-run-inside-to-avoid-a-hail-of-diamonds

Comment: Friend says no.  "Yeah, that's not it. It had two kids, playing outside. They nearly get caught in the diamond rain and one of them gets a cut from one of the shards."

Comment: Both of those links feature kids playing outside.

Comment: [Oh. It's raining again.](https://www.cartooncuisine.com/wp-content/uploads/2019/06/Raining-Again-Screenshot.jpg)

Answer (score 2):

Could be "[Trillions](https://www.isfdb.org/cgi-bin/title.cgi?19378)" by Nicholas Fisk, published in 1971?
From Wikipedia:

> A mysterious shower of tiny crystals fall all over Earth. No-one knows where they came from, or what their purpose is, but they certainly behave strangely. Bonding together they mimic strange, and sometimes threatening, shapes. A boy with a microscope is just as likely to find out the answers as all the scientific pundits

[There is quite a nice summary here](https://omnibus.home.blog/2019/02/02/trillions-by-nicholas-fisk/).

The main characters are all children and are initially caught in the first shower but I don't recall if any are injured.

But the planet is just Earth and they are not sold to off-worlders (there are no other inhabited planets) although one of the children does have an out-of-body experience to another planet.

I think most of Fisk's work would be considered as for children or young adults - certainly that was the age I read this.